# How to load a gzipped rdf file to rdf4j Repository?

Tags: java, rdf, gzip, rdf4j

I want to load a gzipped rdf file into a `org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.Repository`. During the upload, status messages must be logged to the console. The size of my rdf file is ~1GB of uncompressed or ~50MB of compressed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Variant 1

The following sample will load an `InputStream` with gzipped data into an in-memory rdf repository. The zipped format is supported directly by rdf4j.
Every 100000th statement will be printed to stdout using the `RepositoryConnectionListenerAdapter`.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Resource;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Value;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.Repository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.event.base.NotifyingRepositoryConnectionWrapper;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.event.base.RepositoryConnectionListenerAdapter;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.memory.MemoryStore;

public class MyTripleStore {

    Repository repo;

    /**
     * Creates an inmemory triple store
     * 
     */
    public MyTripleStore() {
        repo = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
        repo.initialize();
    }

    /**
     * @param in gzip compressed data on an inputstream
     * @param format the format of the streamed data
     */
    public void loadZippedFile(InputStream in, RDFFormat format) {
        System.out.println("Load zip file of format " + format);
        try (NotifyingRepositoryConnectionWrapper con =
                new NotifyingRepositoryConnectionWrapper(repo, repo.getConnection());) {
            RepositoryConnectionListenerAdapter myListener =
                    new RepositoryConnectionListenerAdapter() {
                        private long count = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void add(RepositoryConnection arg0, Resource arg1, IRI arg2, 
                                         Value arg3, Resource... arg4) {
                            count++;
                            if (count % 100000 == 0)
                                    System.out.println("Add statement number " + count + "\n" 
                                    + arg1+ " " + arg2 + " " + arg3);
                        }
                    };
            con.addRepositoryConnectionListener(myListener);
            con.add(in, "", format);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

## Variant 2

This variant implements an `AbstractRDFHandler` to provide the reporting.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Statement;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.Repository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFInserter;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.helpers.AbstractRDFHandler;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.memory.MemoryStore;

public class MyTripleStore {
    Repository repo;

    /**
      * Creates an inmemory triple store
      * 
      */
    public MyTripleStore() {
        repo = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
        repo.initialize();
   }

    /**
     * @param in gzip compressed data on an inputstream
     * @param format the format of the streamed data
     */
    public void loadZippedFile1(InputStream in, RDFFormat format) {
        try (RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection()) {
            MyRdfInserter inserter = new MyRdfInserter(con);
            RDFLoader loader =
                    new RDFLoader(con.getParserConfig(), con.getValueFactory());
            loader.load(in, "", RDFFormat.NTRIPLES, inserter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    class MyRdfInserter extends AbstractRDFHandler {
        RDFInserter rdfInserter;
        int count = 0;

        public MyRdfInserter(RepositoryConnection con) {
            rdfInserter = new RDFInserter(con);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleStatement(Statement st) {
            count++;
            if (count % 100000 == 0)
                System.out.println("Add statement number " + count + "\n"
                        + st.getSubject().stringValue() + " "
                        + st.getPredicate().stringValue() + " "
                        + st.getObject().stringValue());
            rdfInserter.handleStatement(st);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is, how to call the code

```
MyTripleStore ts = new MyTripleStore();
ts.loadZippedFile(new FileInputStream("your-ntriples-zipped.gz"),
            RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually an RDF4J repository will automatically process a compressed (zip/gzip) file correctly, already. So you can simply do this:

```
   RepositoryConnection conn = ... ; // your store connection
   conn.add(new File("file.zip"), null, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES):
```

If you want to include reporting, a different (somewhat simpler) approach  is to use an `org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader` class in combination with an `RDFInserter`:

```
RepositoryConnection conn = ... ; // your store connection
RDFInsert inserter = new RDFInserter(conn);
RDFLoader loader = new RDFLoader(conn.getParserConfig(), conn.getValueFactory());

loader.load(new File("file.zip"), RDFFormat.NTRIPLES, inserter));
```

The RDFLoader takes care of properly uncompressing the (zip or gzip) file.

To get intermediate reporting you can wrap your RDFInserter in your own custom `AbstractRDFHandler` that does the counting and reporting (before passing on to the wrapper inserter).